# rest operations Azure Datalake gen2

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-account

I want to do operations in Azure datalake gen2 using rest operations. I have a service principal with client secret and having owner access on storage account.
I am confused how to construct the request for operations. I can't find any proper example demonstrating it.
The way which I want is to:

1. Get access token
2. Make a put request with bearer authentication method

Below are documents which I am referring

[Access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage)

[Put blob operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)

I want to do it through postman. It would be really helpful if someone can suggest it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one service principal named **`DataLake`** and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I granted **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to that service principal at storage account level like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your storage account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Storage Blob Data Contributor***

[image]

To generate the **access token** via Postman, I used below *parameters*:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:<appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran the below query by including above Bearer token, I got **`Status 201 Created`** like below:

```http
PUT https://<storageaccname>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/test.txt

Authorization:Bearer <token>
x-ms-version:2017-11-09
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
```

**Response:**

[image]

You need to attach the file in **Postman** before running the query like below:

[image]

When I checked the same in Azure Portal, file uploaded to storage account **successfully** like below:

[image]